# table view Warning

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

i have tried the table view sample with the viewcontroller.when im running i got this error may i know wher im making mistake

**WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:` is deprecated in iPhone OS 3.0 with the following note:

> Use the accessory-view and accessory-type properties (for both normal and editing modes) of the UITableViewCell class when configuring table-view cells.

They mean you should set accessoryType/accessoryView properties in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` instead.