# UiTable view warning delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, warnings

When i runing my iphone `UITableView` based application its showing me warning

> WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due
>   to delegate implementation of
>   tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:
>   in .  Please remove your
>   implementation of this method and set
>   the cell properties accessoryType
>   and/or editingAccessoryType to move to
>   the new cell layout behavior.  This
>   method will no longer be called in a
>   future release.

i also follow "set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType" but its again showing me same warning.

Please help me to remove this warning..thanks

Comment: Have you deleted tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath method implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a related question that may have the answer that you are looking for:

[table view Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289808)

Answer (score 1):

Correct, accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath delegate method is deprecated. We should use UITableViewCell's accessoryType and accessoryView properties to put control on right side of Cell.

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
            if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell";
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            }
            return cell;
    }
```